# Multiple optional keys in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

my map function

```
function(doc, meta) {
  emit([doc.city, doc.region], doc.id);
}
```

my query

```
?keys=[["New York", "Northeast"]]
```

this will emit:

```
{ 
  city: 'New York',
  region: Northeast
}
```

If I want use the same map function getting only those cities from Northeast it won't work. is there any way to match only 1 of the keys ? Like...

```
?keys=[[null, "Northeast"]]
```

and outputing

```
[{ 
  city: 'New York',
  region: 'Northeast'
},
{
  city: 'Boston',
  region: 'Northeast'
}]
```

Answer (score 6):

When you are using a query/view into Couchbase you can only read the key from left to right.

So if you want to be able to query on each "part" you need to create a new view that emit (so you can if you want do the 2 emit in the same view or create 2 views)

```
emit(doc.region, doc.city);
```

And query it for example using

```
?startkey=["Northeast"]&endkey["Northeast",{}]
```

Also,as you can see I do not emit the doc.id, this is not necessary because the doc.id is always emitted by Couchbase views.

Comment: This works equally well if one of the key fields (in my case 2nd) is a date.

Comment: Yes but be sure to transform the date into a long or an array dateToArray(doc.yourDate)